# Upgrade my RDLC schema from 2008/01 to 2010/01

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc, page-break

1st Question Asked!! :)

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project in which I have some RDLC report definitions. I have been asked to meet a requirement by where I reset the page # and total pages on a group break. I didn't think this would be a big deal - well I was wrong. :)

I have found a way to reset the page number via code on the report but cannot seem to find a way to reset the total pages.  ie: Page 1 of X, Page 2 of X ... the 'of X' part is what I cannot seem to reset on the group breaks.

Anyway, through some more searching I found that this seems to be a supported feature in Reporting Services ... see this link ... http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/group-level-page-numbering-using-reporting-services-2008-r2/

BUT, this is not available to me in my property page, through some more searching I found this property to be a part of the 2010/01 schema and onwards andNOT a part of the 2008/01 schema my project seems to be using.

So my real question ... Is there a way to upgrade my RDLC report schema from the 2008/01 schema to the 2010/01 schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit reports with BIDS 2008R2 the report schema will be updated automatically. If it's not then you aren't editing the reports with a 2008R2 tool. Install Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008R2 to your machine. It can be found on the SQL installation media.

Before doing this, make sure that the server to which these will be deployed is running SSRS 2008R2!

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer:** I feel downright dirty about this answer, but it worked for me. As with all undocumented hacks, proceed at your own risk.
>
> There must be a better way to do this, but I couldn’t find it. I trust that your .rdlc files are in source control, and that you can rollback to a previously working version if the procedure below causes problems.

Your RDLC file's namespace declaration will look something like this:

[image: RDLC file using 2008 schema]

To coerce Visual Studio (2013 in my case; I have not tested it with any other versions) to upgrade to the 2010 schema, do the following:

1. Open the Toolbox
2. Drag an Indicator onto your report
3. Save your report
4. Delete the newly-added Indicator from your report
5. Save your report

Or, in animated gif form:

[image]

Afterward, your RDLC file's namespace declaration should look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.